# Build a li tag string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm having trouble figuring out why this wont output correctly, the script  is supposed to output a list of each multiple within the range given from the user, how ever, I get no action on the browser, debugging doesn't pick up any issues either:

```
 function findMultiples() {

'use strict';

var startingInt = document.getElementById('startingInt').value ;
var endingInt = document.getElementById('endingInt').value ;
var multiple = document.getElementById('multiple').value ;

var unListOutput ='';
 for (var i = startingInt; i < endingInt ; i--){
    unListOutput +=  ((i/multiple)%2==0) ?'<li>'+ i  + ' is '+multiple+' x '+(i/multiple)+'</li>': '';
            
 }
 unList = document.getElementById('list');
  unList.innerHTML = unListOutput ;
return false;

} 

function init() {
'use strict';
document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = findMultiples;
} 
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Try posting a demo here http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You might try `i++`, since it seems that `startingInt` is less than `endingInt` (given `i < endingInt`).

Comment: that starting int should be higher, its  a descending range , so the first input is higher than the ending number..i think lol my brain hurts from logical reasoning lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two issues on your code:

1. **i** needs to be incremental => `(i++)`
2. **unList** requires *var* keyword => `var unList = document.getElementById('list');`

so your code could generate your list like the code below:

> ```
>  <script>
>     function findMultiples() {
>         'use strict';
>         var startingInt = 0; //for the test purpose
>         var endingInt = 10; //for the test purpose
>         var multiple = 2; //for the test purpose
>
>         var unListOutput = '';
>
>         for (var i = startingInt; i < endingInt ; i++) {
>             unListOutput += ((i / multiple) % 2 == 0) ? '<li>' + i + ' is ' + multiple + ' x ' + (i / multiple) + '</li>' : '';
>         }
>
>         var unList = document.getElementById('list');
>         unList.innerHTML = unListOutput;
>         //return false;
>     }
>
>
>     function init() {
>
>         findMultiples(); //for the test purpose
>     }
>     window.onload = init;
> </script>
> ```

html element:

> ```
>   <ul id="list"></ul>
> ```

Comment: maybe my math is wrong , should it just be i%multiple == 0?

Comment: the current result for my code above is like : 0 is 2 x 0
4 is 2 x 2
8 is 2 x 4 so it totally depends on what you want to do

Comment: ok cool , so i if i needed the list to descend I would just reverse the start int and end int ?

Comment: then it will be look like this **for (var i = endingInt ; i > startingInt ; i--) {..}**

Comment: Thanks so much guys, I will make revisions now, I feel like the more I submerse my self, and try to grasp what I'm doing , the code becomes secondary ,